# Getting the KML color code from colordialog box more efficiently

Tags: c#

Kml uses an 8 digit HEX color format. The traditional Hex format for red looks like #FF0000. In Kml, red would look like this FFFF0000. The first 2 digits are for opacity (alpha). Color format is in AABBGGRR. I was looking for a way to set the color as well as the opacity and return it in a string to be placed in an attribute of a KML.

```
string color
string polyColor;
int opacity;
decimal percentOpacity;
string opacityString;

//This allows the user to set the color with a colorDialog adding the chosen color to a string in HEX (without opacity (BBGGRR))
private void btnColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        btnColor.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;
        Color clr = colorDialog1.Color;
        color = String.Format("{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", clr.B, clr.G, clr.R); //Color returned in Hex format
    }
}

//This method takes the Opacity (0% - 100%) set by a textbox and gets the HEX value. Then adds Opacity to Color and adds it to a string.
private void PolyColor()
{
    percentOpacity = ((Convert.ToDecimal(txtOpacity.Text) / 100) * 255);
    percentOpacity = Math.Floor(percentOpacity);  //rounds down
    opacity = Convert.ToInt32(percentOpacity);
    opacityString = opacity.ToString("x");
    polyColor = opacityString + color;
}
```

Comment: “The traditional Hex format for black looks like #FF0000.” That's not black, that's red.

Comment: If the format is AABBGGRR, shoudn't red be FF0000FF instead of FFFF000000?

Comment: @Pierre-Luc Pineeault, Thats blue...and there is only 4 zeros not 6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `System.Drawing` namespace lives the `ColorTranslator` class which has an `ToHtml()` method which can be used here. A good way would be to create extension methods for this task. The first extension method will be named `ToKMLColor` and will expect a String parameter.

By using `dec.TryParse()` and `Math.Min()` we assure that the given parameter is a valid representation of a decimal/number with a maximum of `100`. If the `TryParse` won't succeed, we assume that the opacity will be `0`.
After we have got the computed (`/100*255`) opacity value we pass it

```
public static string ToKMLColor(this Color color, String percentageOpacity)
{
    decimal opacity = 0;
    decimal.TryParse(percentageOpacity, out opacity);

    opacity = Math.Min(opacity, 100);
    opacity = Math.Floor(opacity / 100 * 255);

    return color.ToKMLColor(opacity);
}
```

to the overloaded `ToKMLColor()` method, which takes a decimal parameter. After converting the decimal to an int we pass it

```
public static string ToKMLColor(this Color color, decimal opacity)
{
    return color.ToKMLColor(Convert.ToInt32(opacity));
}
```

to the overloaded `ToKMLColor()` method, which takes an integer parameter. Here we call the `ToString()` method with the `X2` format to get the hex representation of the integer parameter and concat the return value of the `ToHex()` by using the `Substring()` method to remove the leading `#`.

```
public static string ToKMLColor(this Color color, int opacity)
{
    return opacity.ToString("X2") + color.ToHex().Substring(1);
}
public static String ToHex(this Color color)
{
    return System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Color.FromArgb(0, color));
}
```

Now we can call

```
polyColor = colorDialog1.Color.ToKMLColor(txtOpacity.Text);
```